# Javascript map nested array

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a nested array of objects like:

```
const data = {
  "rates": {
    "2019-09-04": {
      "USD": 0.1275393858,
    },
    "2019-09-05": {
      "USD": 0.1275638511,
},   "2019-09-06": {
      ...
}
```

All I want is make the array flat, and return the result as:

```
"rates": {
   1:{
    "date": "2019-09-04"
    "rate": "0.1275393858",
    "currency":"USD"
    },
  } 2:{ ...
```

I have tried `Object.key` but i cannot destruct the 'rates'.

it is what i have tried.

```
const newData = {
rates: Object.keys(data.rates).map((date, idx) => {

  return {
        date,
        rate: data.rates

  }
  })
 };
```

Do I have to "double map" the data in order to get what i want?

Comment: Just FYI, there are no arrays in any of your examples. Maybe you meant nested objects?

Comment: How is the result "flatter" than the input? You're just replacing the date with a number. This doesn't change the depth of the object

Comment: sorry i m new to coding. i mess up with nested object and nested array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways (as always) like using `map`, `reduce` or the simple one is to loop over the `rates` entries and recreate another object with the structure you want.

It should look something like this:

```js
const obj = {
  "rates": {
    "2019-09-04": {
      "USD": 0.1275393858,
    },
    "2019-09-05": {
      "USD": 0.1275638511,
    } 
  }
}


const transformedObj = {rates: {}}
let i = 0
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj.rates)) {
    transformedObj.rates[i++] = {
      date: key, 
      rate: Object.values(value)[0],
      currency: Object.keys(value)[0]
    }
}

console.log(transformedObj)
```

## Update:


If you don't want to use the index then do like this:

```js
const obj = {
  "rates": {
    "2019-09-04": {
      "USD": 0.1275393858,
    },
    "2019-09-05": {
      "USD": 0.1275638511,
    } 
  }
}


const transformedObj = {rates: {}}

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj.rates)) {
    transformedObj.rates[key] = {
      date: key, 
      rate: Object.values(value)[0],
      currency: Object.keys(value)[0]
    }
}

console.log(transformedObj)
```

Comment: hello if i want to  do like ' "rates": {
    "2019-09-04": {
      "date": "2019-09-04",
      "rate": 0.1275393858,
      "currency": "USD"
    },
with no increment number how can i do it

Comment: Would this work for rates having multiple currrencies?

Comment: @k0pernikus I didn't want to write code for some hypothesis. So the answer is no.

Comment: @Rachellllls I have updated for your second request... Please check if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The "double map" may not be sufficient enough. Though the idea is valid, your problem consists of "getting the properties of an object" twice, while also assigning its right values to it.

A solution using two maps could look like this:

```
const dates = Object.keys(data.rates);
const results = dates.map((date) => {
    const currencies = Object.keys(data.rates[date]);
    return currencies.map(currency => {
        return {
            date: date,
            rate: data.rates[date][currency],
            currency: currency,
        };
    });
})
```

Though this will be an array of arrays! This makes sense if you assume you have a rate with two currencies:

```
"2019-09-04": {
    "USD": 0.1275393858,
    "EUR": 1.47455,
},
```

This alone yields one array with two elements. An each other rate may generate a dynamic amount of objects in their own array.

You need to flatten that array of arrays. Alas, [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) is not widely supported.

So you may be better off using a library like lodash.

So with that being said you get your wanted result via:

```
_.flatten(results), null, 4)
```

Lodash also supports a flatMap, then a solution could be written like:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";

const data = {
    "rates": {
        "2019-09-04": {
            "USD": 0.1275393858,
            "EUR": 1.47455,
        },
        "2019-09-05": {
            "USD": 0.1275638511,
        },
    },
};

const dates = Object.keys(data.rates);
const results = _.flatMap(dates, (date) => {
    const currencies = Object.keys(data.rates[date]);
    return currencies.map(currency => {
        return {
            date: date,
            rate: data.rates[date][currency],
            currency: currency,
        };
    });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 4));
```

Will print:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2019-09-04",
        "rate": 0.1275393858,
        "currency": "USD"
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-09-04",
        "rate": 1.47455,
        "currency": "EUR"
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-09-05",
        "rate": 0.1275638511,
        "currency": "USD"
    }
]
```

Comment: thats a good example of doing this Thank you I learnt a lot for ur code and explaination!